# Play Developer BETA testing approvals

Tags: android, google-play

How long does it normally take on average for a brand new app to be approved for the BETA testing feature on Play Developer Store once it has been submitted?

Answer (score 0):

There is no fixed time, but I believe it follows the same process as normally publishing an application, which, based off my experience, takes around 1-3 hours.